# Website Slow At Loading The Login Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC website which I am developing, and I recently deployed it on a test server so the client could give some initial feedback.

I have noticed that on the live server there is a considerable delay in loading the login form, of around 20-30 seconds. Once you are logged in, the system functions just fine, and is responsive.

If you log out, and return to the login page, it is once again slow.

It doesn't appear to be an issue with the apppool spooling up, as it happens every time on the page, not just once, and all items appear to be loading.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Below is the BaseController from which all controllers enherit, plus the account login controller.

```
protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {



        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            try
            {
                AccountDataContext = new AccountDAL.DataContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"]);
                // set the current user. 
                CurrentUser = AccountDataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name);
                AccountDataContext.CurrentAccount = CurrentUser.Account;
                ViewBag.CurrentUser = CurrentUser;
                ViewBag.Account = CurrentUser.Account;

                SystemDataContext = new SystemDAL.DataContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"], CurrentUser.Account.Database);

                // setup the account based on the users settings
                ViewBag.Theme = "Default"; // hard coded for now
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // if the previous threw an exception, then the logged in user has been deleted
                // log them out
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Session.Abandon();

                // clear the authentication cookie
                var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            }
        }

        base.ExecuteCore();
    }
```

and the Accounts controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if(AccountDataContext == null)
                AccountDataContext = new AccountDAL.DataContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"]);

            var user = AccountDataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == model.UserName && x.Password == model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Not related, but, how are your local (or not) contexts disposed ?

Comment: What happens when no user is authenticated ? In executeCore CurrentUser should be null, isn'it  ? so `AccountDataContext.CurrentAccount = CurrentUser.Account;` should raise an exception then redirect to login page, then raise, then....

Comment: yes the data contexts :)

Comment: @tschmit007 I dont dispose of them :S Where would I do this? With regards to the CurrentUser - the check "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" would be false, so none of that would be executed if there is no logged in user.

Comment: have you looked at Fiddler, or Chrome Dev Tools to see where it's actually taking so much time? What you've shown looks fairly straight-forward, so need more information (not just code). Maybe IIS configuration/logs, etc.

Comment: which Web.Optimization package version are you using?

Comment: Do you have authentication configured correctly in your web.config? If not, the issue mentioned by @tschmit007 could arise as `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` would always be true.

Comment: One big read flag is the line

    "catch (Exception)"

Any exception could be occuring in that block of code and you wouldn't know it. My guess is that there is an exception occuring, albeit not the one you are expecting, but it's not reported since you are catching all and any expceitons. If you want to work out if the account has been deleted by catching an exception, only catch the relevant exception type and ignore other exceptions. Or better yet, check without using an exception, in this case, checking if your accountdatacontext query returns null.

Comment: @toasties - I've tried removing that, but it doesn't make any difference. The code is the same as another project that has been in production for around 2 years without issue.

Comment: Having looked again at the browser feedback, the page load time is almost always between 29 and 31 seconds, suggesting there is a timeout taking place somewhere in the code?

Comment: Also maybe worth noting that the system works fine on my local machine when run through Vs/IIS Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the slowdown only seems to affect the login pages, I took a closer look at the Account controller which they both use (no other account functions implemented at this time).

I found the following code at the top of the controller:

```
public AccountController()
         : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
```

Removing this declaration cured the issue. I'm not sure what it is or where it came from, I think it's from the original MS default implementation authentication. I don't have an ApplicationDbContext, so I think it was waiting on this request to time out before proceeding.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things will improve performance:

- First and foremost : Deploy your site in **`Release`** mode if you care anything at all about performance. Here a great [article](http://encosia.com/a-harsh-reminder-about-the-importance-of-debug-false/) from Dave Ward about it.

  `<compilation targetFramework="your framework version" debug="false">`
- If you are not using `webforms` view engine (Which i assume you are not) jus disable it and use `Razor` only and to take it a little further, allow just chtml files

  `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
  IViewEngine RazorEngine = new RazorViewEngine() { FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml" } };
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(RazorEngine);`
- Configure Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool (IIS 7)  [Here's the link](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization)

---

### EDIT1:

Based on your last comment mentioning that the app is running fine in your local `IIS`. I would recommend that you start focusing on analyzing the requests on your remote `IIS` , here's a [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)  to a tool that you can use.

In order to trace successful requests as well (And you should do that in your case) set the `status` to **200** here's a [tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr) on that as well.

Comment: Site is deployed in Release mode. I'm using IIS7.5, but the app pool is set to not shut down on idle. I don't believe this is the issue, as it happens every time you visit or refresh the login page.

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` are you using?

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />

Answer (score 0):

Comment out your data access code and run it. Does that speed things up? Or add Debug.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now) and see where the long gap is. There might be a delay connecting to the database

Answer (score -1):

In application pool setting There is setting called Load User profile. Set it to true it will help you to make your site faster.